# How to reduce Tumblr photoset posts size and keep the original ph-set layout?

Tags: themes

I want to reduce them to a maximum 200px width and keep the same layout with the 10px spacing the photos have. Also I don't want to style the posts to be that wide and use overflow:hidden that will only cut off the photosets.

Comment: Without seeing what you've tried, offhand I'm going to say set CSS rules as thus: `.photoset_row{ height: auto !important; width: auto !important; } .photoset_row img { width: auto !important; max-width: 200px; }`

Comment: Never mind CSS -- I wrote a jQuery solution. I'm adding it, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## jQuery Solution

For this solution you will need the latest version of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the jQuery plugin [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) included in the `head` of the theme before the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('iframe.photoset').each(function() {
            var i = this;
            $(i).attr("onload", "ps_resize(this)");
            var s = $(i).attr("src");
            s = s.replace(/\/500\//, "/200/");
            $(i).attr("src", s);
        });
     });
    function ps_resize(i) {
        $(i).contents().find("body").imagesLoaded(function() {
            $(i).attr("width", 200);
            $(i).attr("height", $(this).height());
         });
         return false;
    }
</script>
```

### What Solution Does

1. When the DOM is ready, find all the photoset iFrames
2. For each iFrame...

   - set the "onload" attribute to your frame resizing function
   - get the frame's source url, change the size (e.g. 500) to 200
   - set the frame's source url (this will cause it to reload with a smaller photoset)
3. In the resizing function...

   - wait for the images to load
   - set the frame width to 200
   - set the frame height to the new height of the photoset

### Additional Code for Infinite Scroll

If you are using the [Infinite Scroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) jQuery Plugin, you will need to additionally include this in your `success` callback function:

```
...
$(newElements).find('iframe.photoset').each(function() {
    var i = this;
    $(i).attr("onload", "ps_resize(this)");
    var s = $(i).attr("src");
    s = s.replace(/\/500\//, "/200/");
    $(i).attr("src", s);
 });
...
```

Obviously, if you're using Infinite Scroll, I would suggest defining a `function` that is called on each iFrame on both the initial load and the scroll so you don't have repeated code to maintain.

Comment: I don't know if you'll see this but I'm completely lost with the infinite scroll part. I'm using the latest version of masonry with the inf-scroll. I'm sorry for troubling you but I'll ask for help again.

Comment: @user1992094 Let me see your `infinitescroll` and `masonry` calls and I'll tell you where to put it.

Comment: @korvoj Here you go. Let me know if you have any issues. http://pastebin.com/fWJu30Ms

Comment: It cooperates with the rest of the code and does its purpose but under each ph-set post now there is a gap that would be normally filled with the ph-set if it was the original width no matter if it's 500; 400; or 250. (side note: I changed the source form 500 to 250 and width from 200px to 160px)